# Couchdb and pouchdb are not storing info in the same place

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm a little confused about couchdb / pouchdb.

Here's my setup.

I'm running `couchdb` to get it up and running.

To confirm I run this, `curl localhost:5984`, and it works.

Navigate to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html` and see this:

[image: couchdb-admin]

Then I use `node` and `pouchdb` to connect and insert a doc.

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
var test = new PouchDB('test')

test.info()
.then(function (info) {
  console.log(info)
})
.catch(console.error)

test.put({
  '_id': '308',
  'hello': 'world'
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

I run this `node index.js` and get a ok response for both.

I check the `couchdb` admin (above) and see it hasn't changed. It seems no data has been saved.

I look in the node projects directory and see there's a `test` folder. There must be some issue where pouch thinks that the database directory is local and the `couchdb` directory is somewhere else.

To figure out where couch is storing info I run `couchdb -c`

```
$ couchdb -c
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

Which gives me the location of the config files.

I can see in `default.ini` this:

```
database_dir = /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb
view_index_dir = /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb
```

I don't understand how or why this connection between where `couchdb` thinks the db is and where `pouchdb` thinks it is, is different.

How can I fix this, and make `pouchdb` use the dir specified for `couchdb`?

**Update:**

Just tried this and I still don't see it in the `couchdb` interface.

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb')

// var test = new PouchDB('test')

var MyPrefixedPouch = PouchDB.defaults({
  prefix: '/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb'
});

var test = new MyPrefixedPouch('test');

test.info().then(function (info) {
  console.log(info)
})

test.put({
  '_id': '308',
  'hello': 'world'
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you've understood the way pouchdb works. When you run it in node the way you are it uses [leveldb](http://leveldb.org/) as a backend. It's writing a data file in the test directory of your project (I wonder what would happen if you had tests there!).

It doesn't talk to your couchbase server at all.

If you pass the uri to your couch server in the constructor, you'll talk to your couchbase instance:

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/myremotedb')
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, perfect explanation. I thought it automatically connected to the localhost server.

Comment: @ThomasReggi PouchDB can work without any couchdb instance, when you're configuring it this way, it will allow it to sync with couchdb but technically pouchdb alone is a couchdb server in javascript.